# Python reverse lookup classes by identifiers

Tags: python, identifier

I have several "model" classes (ModelFoo, ModelBar, ModelBaz, ModelQux) that can get instantiated by a client with varying identifiers. In order to map the identifiers to the correct model classes I've created a mapping class:

```
class ModelTypes(object):
  """ Enumeration of supported class types, mapping userland identifier to constructor.
  """
  # Multiple names per model type enable us to run several instances in parallel
  FooModel = ModelFoo
  fooMod = ModelFoo
  foo = Foo
  ff = Foo

  Bar = ModelBar
  bar = ModelBar

  Baz = ModelBaz
  baz = ModelBaz

  Qux = ModelQux
  qux = ModelQux


  @classmethod
  def getTypes(cls):
    """ Return the names of the attributes explicitly defined above.
    """
    for attrName in dir(cls):
      attrValue = getattr(cls, attrName)
      if (isinstance(attrValue, type) and
          issubclass(attrValue, acceptableClassImplementations)):
        yield attrName # attrName is an acceptable model name
```

That is, I use the `ModelTypes` class for reverse lookups, where I need to map a simple identifier (e.g. `qux`) back to a corresponding class (`ModelQux`). But this is getting tedious to add all the identifiers a client may use. Is there a standard/suggested way to map keywords to classes?

Comment: Why not maintain a little dictionary?

Comment: @JosepValls The class is cleaner, but even so a dictionary would not solve my problem of having to manually update it with identifiers.

Comment: How is a class cleaner than `modelmap = {'FooModel': ModelFoo, 'fooMod': ModelFoo,} # etc`? Also, where does the allowable list of identifiers come from?

Comment: I still second @chepner and I wouldn't do it but if I wanted to do what you seem to want, maybe you could add a little field `alias` to your classes with a set of their aliases. Have all your classes inherit some kind of model class and then call `.__subclasses__()` on this model where you can iterate over all the classes and check for membership in the alias set.

Answer (score 0):

if all you want is less writing to define multiple variables to the same value there is a syntax for that:

```
x = y = z = 0
print(x,y,z)
```

so you could do:

```
  FooModel = fooModel = ModelFoo
  foo = ff = Foo

  Bar = bar = ModelBar
  Baz = baz = ModelBaz
  Qux = quz = ModelQux
```

But if you want something more automated then you want a `dict` which is *the only built in mapping object*, however it can be implemented to respond to attributes the same way as to items:

```
class ModelTypes(dict):
    __slots__ = ()#otherwise each object would have a second dict used for attributes

    #this will mean d.x acts the same as d['x']
    __getattr__ = dict.__getitem__
    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__
    __delattr__ = dict.__delitem__
    #would you still need this or would you just use .keys() instead?
    def getTypes(self): #maybe take an optional argument to use in issubclass()?
        return [name for name,cls in self.items() \
                 if (isinstance(cls,type) and 
                     issubclass(cls, acceptableClassImplementations))]
```

As well any subclass of `dict` can define a `__missing__` method which is called if you try to get a key that doesn't exist, so you can implement it to check the dict again ignoring case and checking the documented names of the classes:

```
    def __missing__(self,key):
        #if the user uses different case this will check again with generic case
        #also checks against name attribute of types
        if not isinstance(key,str) or key=="":
            raise KeyError(key)

        key = key.lower()
        for name,cls in self.items():
            if key == name.lower()):
                return cls
            if key == getattr(cls,"__name__","").lower():
                return cls
        raise KeyError(key)
```

then you can define one name corresponding to one class and all variations will be handled:

```
class FooModel:pass
class FooBar:pass
class ModelQux:pass

#other then added commas this is just as clean as inside a class
models = ModelTypes(foo=FooModel,
                    bar=FooBar,
                    qux=ModelQux)

print(models.foo is models["foo"])   #.foo works from overriding __getattr__
print(models.foo is models.Foo)      #'Foo' works because __missing__ checked it again with lower case
print(models.foo is models.FooModel) #'FooModel' works because __missing__ also checks class names
print(models.foo is models.foomodel) #it checks the .lower() of key against .lower() of class name
```